# Code to submit boolean button with keypresses

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make my code submit a boolean button with two options. I am trying to trigger the S and K keypress to submit each button. I saw the following code, but when I try it, it doesn't run.

This is my HTML code. Each button has a function that give me a timestamp of the click, submit the page and save the option that the participant chooses (A or B).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <p style="text-align: center;">
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" 
    onclick="myFunction()" name="offer_accepted1" id="of1A" value="True">&nbsp;A</button> 
     <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large"
    onclick="myFunction()" name="offer_accepted1" id="of1B" value="False">B</button>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="timestamp1" value="0" />
    {{ form.timestamp1.errors }}

     <input type="text" id="c1" name="c1" value="0" />
     {{ form.c1.errors }}
<!--The keypress code-->

     <script>
    var input = document.getElementById("of1A");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
       if (event.keyCode === 75) {
     event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("of1A").click();
    });

    var input = document.getElementById("of1B");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 83) {
       event.preventDefault();
       document.getElementById("of1B").click();
      }
    });


//The function that gives me a timestamp

function myFunction() {
  var n = Date.now();
  document.getElementById("c1").value = n;
    }

    </script>

</body>
```

Without the keypress code the code runs in the next way:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var n = Date.now();
  document.getElementById("c1").value = n;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" 
    onclick="myFunction()" name="offer_accepted1" value="True">&nbsp;A</button> 
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large"
    onclick="myFunction()" name="offer_accepted1" value="False">B</button>
</p>
<input type="hidden" name="timestamp1" value="0" />
{{ form.timestamp1.errors }}

<input type="text" id="c1" name="c1" value="0" />
{{ form.c1.errors }}
```

Comment: Where is document.getElementById("myBtn") dom element with id `myBtn`?
As there is no this element, there is nothing to do with keypress event, I think.

Comment: I am little newbie using JS. should I put   document.getElementById("myBtn") with the timestamp id or with the id of the button ?

Comment: I mean there is no html element with myBtn id.
i.e: <button onclick="myfunction()" id="myBtn">Submit</button> or
You could just call myFunction function directly with addEventListener with keyup event.

Comment: Oh yeah. I changed it. Right now the ID is the ID of each button. But that doesn't works

Comment: Please debug in case.
Make sure that keyup event works well. Try something output strings with console.log command.

Try check step by step. This way you could check what is wrong.